# Usage of data attribute VS custom element attribute

Tags: polymer

I understand that create a custom attribute on a custom element in Polymer allows us to watch for changes to that attribute by specifying a listener. But if I just need to expose a data from my custom element when do I use data attribute and when to use a Polymer's custom attribute?

*I also understand that data-* takes only strings

Comment: One thing I noticed is when I use data- attribute to bind data the changes are not getting triggered to the bounded attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll pretty much always want to use Polymer's custom attributes unless your attribute has the same name as a built-in attribute (like `title`). As you noticed, the change handlers will not work with `data-` attributes.

Comment: Just to add... we recommend custom attributes because you can publish properties in Polymer as attributes. This allows you to take advantage of Polymer's data-binding features and `<prop>Changed()` handlers. `data-*` attrs aren't observable in the same way to Polymer's internals.